# Ruby: How do I share a global variable amongst threads that are running an object.method

Tags: ruby, multithreading, global-variables

I am running a ruby script that creates several threads.

I want to make the threads have access to a common variable that lets the main thread know when to join the threads.

I am trying to do this with a $global variable, but the threads don't seem the be able to access the $global.

```
class IO_ 
  def change(number)
    sleep(60 * number)
    $trade_executed = true
  end
end 

io = IO_.new 
numbers = 1, 2
$threads = {}
$trade_executed = false

def start_threads(numbers)
  numbers.each do |number|
    $threads[number] = Thread.new {io.change(number)}
  end
end

start_threads(numbers)

while true
  p $trade_executed
  p $threads
  sleep(10)
end
```

The above $trade_executed will always be 'false'.

But if I move the method change outside of the io object it works.

Comment: Re, "a...variable that lets the main thread know when to join..." Why would your main thread need to know when to join? What is it going to keep doing up until that moment? Normally thread A joins thread B when there's nothing else left that  thread A can do before thread B is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the function `start_threads`. You called `io.change(number)` in that function, but the local variable `io` is not defined in that function. The consequence is that both threads died due to `NameError`.

You can change the `start_threads` function as this:

```
def start_threads(numbers, io)
  numbers.each do |number|
    $threads[number] = Thread.new {io.change(number)}
  end
end
```

and call it like this:

```
start_threads(numbers, io)
```

Comment: Thank you. Objects need to be passed. Got it.